# Confusion about MSAA

Tags: opengl, directx, msaa

I was researching about MSAA and how it works. I understand the concept how it works and what is the idea behind it. Basically, if the center of triangle covers the center of the pixel this is processed ( in case of the non-msaa). However, If msaa is involved. Let's say 4xmsaa then it will sample 4 other point as sub-sample. Pixel shader will execute per-pixel. However, occlusion,and coverage test will be applied for each sub-pixel. The point I'm confused is I imagine the pixel as little squares on the screen and I couldn't understand how sub-sampling points are determined inside the sample rectangle. How computer aware of one pixels sub-sample locations. And if there is only one square how it sub-sampled colors are determined.(If there is one square then there should be only one color). Lastly,How each sub-sample might have different depth value if it was basically same pixel.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, if the center of triangle covers the center of the pixel this is processed ( in case of the non-msaa).

No, that's not making sense. The center of a triangle is just a point, and that pint falling onto a pixel center means nothing. Standard rasterizing rule is: if the center of the pixel lies *inside* of the triangle, a fragment is produced (with special rules for cases where the center of the pixel lies exactly on the boundary of the triangle).

> The point I'm confused is I imagine the pixel as little squares on the screen and I couldn't understand how sub-sampling points are determined inside the sample rectangle.

No Idea what you mean by "sample rectangle", but keeping that aside: If you use some coordinate frame of reference where a pixel is 1x1 units in area, than you can simply use fractional parts for describing locations within a pixel.

Default OpenGL Window space uses a convention where (0,0) is the lower left *corner* of the bottom left pixel, and `(width,height)` is the upper-right corner of the top-right pixel, and all the pixel centers are at half integers `.5`.

The rasterizer of a real GPU does work with *fixed-point* representations, and the D3D spec requires that it has at least 8 bits of fractional precision for sub-pixel locations (GL leaves the exact precsision up to the implementor).

Note that at this point, the pixel raster is not relevant at all. A coverage sample is just testing if some 2D point lies inside or outside of an 2D triangle, and a point is always a mathematically infinitely small entity with an area of 0. The conventions for the coordinate systems to do this calculation in can be arbitrarly defined.

> And if there is only one square how it sub-sampled colors are determined.(If there is one square then there should be only one color). Lastly,How each sub-sample might have different depth value if it was basically same pixel.

When you use multipsamling, you always use a multisampled framebuffer, which means that for each pixel, there is not a single color, depth, ... value, but there are `n` (your multisampling count, typically between 2 and 16 inclusively). You will need an additional pass to calculate the single per-pixel values needed for displaying the anti-aliased results (the grpahics API might hide this from you when done on the default frambebuffer, but when you work with custom render targets, you have to do this manually).